# Grouping by Month i.e. 30 days from the starting timestamp rather than the actual month

Tags: mysql

I have a monthly offering that gives customers 30 minutes of use every month and I need to tally up their usage and group it by month, but not sure the best way to handle that since the start date could be any day of the month.

Should I prorate?  Convert into full months or count the days?

Is there an ideal way to tally this?  Let's say each month they get 30 minutes of use time, so I want to tally how many minutes were used that "month."

Say there is a minutes used table and the start date for the subscription is 2019-06-13 00:00:00

minutes_used_table:

```
Userid                MinutesUsed               Date

1                         5                    2019-06-19
1                         6                    2019-06-23
1                         8                    2019-06-28
1                         15                   2019-07-05
1                         3                    2019-07-12
1                         8                    2019-07-19
1                         5                    2019-08-14
1                         3                    2019-08-22
1                         1                    2019-08-26
1                         2                    2019-09-13
```

Or, should I prorate it and instead of tracking in 30 day increments, if they start on the 13th of June, should I just count the days from the start date to the end of the month, whatever day that is and then the days from the first of the month until the start date?

Wondering what makes the most sense and how to carry it out?

Comment: I would go with the 30 day interval approach. It might be more appropriate to use a 30.42 day interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(`Date`, @starting_date) DIV @period_length
```

In your particular case it will be

```
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(`Date`, '2019-06-13 00:00:00') DIV 30
```

Answer (score 0):

From coding point of view it's not a big deal to find first date for user, subtract it from dates and count number of 30-days periods.
But this will be very hard to support in future and this solution will have a number of corner cases: for example someone first start to use product at 20 January, after month of usage have been idle for a while and came back in April, 5. What will be right start date for that case?

So I suggest to use calendar months. And may be reduce limit on first month accordingly to the number of days left or give full trial period even on first month as user has ability to spend 30 minutes.